# TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined in discord.js \\\

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("771238821550620703");
   setInterval(function () {
      var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;  
      var memberCountChannel = client.channels.get("886555053421375501");
      memberCountChannel.setName(`╭・：Online :${memberCount}`);
   }, 10000);
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined

I have checked the channel id and server id hundred times but it is still not working..

Comment: Well the problem here is that the variable `guild` is `undefined` meaning `client.guilds.cache.get()` hasn't found any guilds to return, I would suggest console logging `client.guilds.cache` first to see if the guild you are looking for is in there, maybe your bot is not even in that guild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `client.channels.get(...)` is not a function. The correct method would be `client.channels.cache.get(...)`.
2. You should always fetch the guild instead of searching the cache, especially as more guilds get added.

Example:

```js
(async () => {
    const guild = await client.guilds.fetch("771238821550620703");
    setInterval(function () {
        var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
        var memberCountChannel = guild.channels.get("886555053421375501");
        memberCountChannel.setName(`╭・：Online :${memberCount}`);
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Guilds are not uncached. The are cached when the bot joins, or if the bot was in it on start, it is cached.

Comment: @MrMythical There's always a chance that not every guild is cached.

Comment: @MrMythical Only if they have the `GUILDS` intent enabled. Otherwise fetching *is* required